# MWFeedParser RSS Reader doesn't get image

Tags: ios, xml, swift, rss-reader

I'm trying to get image from RSS Feed with MWFeedParser. I'm getting feed items, but when I was try to reach image, something is missing in `content` value. It has to be there, but it's not.

So I changed the content value with link. Link is like that:

[http://www.uefa.com/uefaeuro/news/newsid=2372826.html?rss=2372826+Italy\'s+\'BBC\'+spell+out+programme+for+solidity](http://www.uefa.com/uefaeuro/news/newsid=2372826.html?rss=2372826%20Italy%5C's%20%5C'BBC%5C'%20spell%20out%20programme%20for%20solidity)

Then now `match` value is getting nil. I don't figured out what is the problem.

This is my RSS Feed url what I'm use to :

```
let url = NSURL(string: "feed://www.uefa.com/rssfeed/uefaeuro/rss.xml")
```

This is my code to get image from RSS Feed:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("homeFeed", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! HomeFeedTableViewCell

        cell.homeFeedImageView.image = UIImage(named: "placeholder")

        let item = feedItem[indexPath.row] as MWFeedItem?
        cell.homeFeedTextView.text = item?.title

        if item?.link != nil{
            let htmlContent = item!.link as NSString
            var imageSource = ""

            let rangeOfString = NSMakeRange(0, htmlContent.length)
            do{
            let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "<img.*?src=\"([^\"]*)\"", options: [])

                if htmlContent.length > 0 {
                    let match = regex.firstMatchInString(htmlContent as String, options: [], range: rangeOfString)
                    if match != []{
                        let imageUrl = htmlContent.substringWithRange((match!.rangeAtIndex(2))) as NSString
                        print(imageUrl)

                        if NSString(string: imageUrl.lowercaseString).rangeOfString("feedburner").location == NSNotFound{
                            imageSource = imageUrl as String
                        }
                    }

                }

                if imageSource != ""{
                    cell.homeFeedImageView.setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: imageSource)!, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder"))
                }else{
                    cell.homeFeedImageView.image = UIImage(named: "placeholder")
                }
            }
            catch let error as NSError{
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }


        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to set image with URLRequest instead, as shown below:

```
if imageSource != ""{
        let request = URLRequest(url: Foundation.URL(string: imageSource)!)
        cell.imageView?.setImageWith(request, placeholderImage: nil, success: { [weak cell] request, response, image in
        if cell != nil {
            cell!.imageView!.image = image
        }

        if self.tableView.visibleCells._bridgeToObjectiveC().contains(cell!) {
            self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
        }
        }, failure:nil)
}
```

[working screenshot of your RSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wW1R.png)

Image is tiny in the screenshot but that is due to my imageview config. I am guessing your imageview is configured to fit bigger image.

Good Luck!

***Note: The code above is for Swift 3.